# Why does creating a package need MongoDB

Tags: packages, package-designer

I'm using sc8.2 and today, creating a small package was taking forever. Nothing in logs too.
The MongoDB service was not running. After starting it again, the package creation went fine.

Why is MongoDB service necessary to create a package.

Also, for 9.3 there is no MongoDB. So, is there any such service to be up for creating the package.

Comment: Do you have any custom processor for http requests? Anything in the logs from the time when you were trying to create a package and  the service was not running?

Comment: @MarekMusielak I'm not sure about the logs if they are related to MongoDB. Though there is no issue now, I was just curious about why is this service necessary & what abt 9.3 in case of troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary in clean Sitecore. I rather suspect it's some custom code in your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reason for this issue is that you have `<setting name="Xdb.Enabled" value="true" />` in your Sitecore.Xdb.config.
This setting is true by default. When this is set to true, then the **ANALYTICS** key is read from the connectionstring.config and the interaction with MongoDB starts.

If you do not need analytics in your instance then this value can be set to **false** through a configuration patch. Then it will not matter if the MongoDB service is running or not.

About the Sitecore 9.3, the above applies to Sitecore 9.3 as well. The only difference is that the data source will not be Mongo in case of Sitecore 9.3 but the flow will remain same.

I hope this answers the question.